# Reinvesting and accumulated values

Tags: finance

I'm having trouble understanding the solution for this problem

> Susan invests Z at the end of each year for seven years at an effective annual interest rate of 5%.  the interest credited at the end of each year is reinvested at an annual of 6%.  The accumulated value at the end of 7 years is X.
>
> Lori invests Z at the end of each year for fourteen years at an effective annual interest rate of 2.5%.  the interest credited at the end of each year is reinvested at an annual of 3%.  The accumulated value at the end of 14 years is Y.
>
> Find $\frac YX$

The solution gives a formula:

$Accumulated Value = NZ + .05Z(Is)_{\overline6|.06}$

Where N is the number of years, and Z is the deposit amount.

I don't understand where this formula came from? Is there anyway to solve this question other than using this formula?

Answer (score 1):

Observe the amount of money at each time
\begin{align}
t&=1 & &z\\
t&=2 & &z(1+i)+z=\color{blue}{2z}+\color{red}{iz}\\
t&=3 & &\color{blue}{2z}(1+i)+z=\color{blue}{3z}+\color{red}{2iz}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
t&=n & &\color{blue}{(n-1)z}(1+i)+z=\color{blue}{nz}+\color{red}{(n-1)iz}\\
\end{align}
The interest part will be subtracted each year and invested at rate $j$. So we have an increasing annuity $k(iz)$ for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$ for the interest part.
Then the future value will be
$$
FV=nz+iz\,(Is)_{\overline{n-1}|\,j}
$$
So the future value for Susan will be
$$
x=7z+0.05\,z\,(Is)_{\overline{6}|\,0.06}
$$
and the future value for Lori will be
$$
y=14z+0.025\,z\,(Is)_{\overline{13}|\,0.03}
$$
Thus 
$$
\frac{x}{y}=\frac{7+0.05\,(Is)_{\overline{6}|\,0.06}}{14+0.025\,(Is)_{\overline{13}|\,0.03}}
$$